# Would overwriting a polymorphic object byte-by-byte in memory ever be valid in C++?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, standards, memcpy

This is more of a 'what if' question than a practical one. Assume that I allocate some polymorphic objects in such a way that the allocator always reserves enough room for the largest object. I want to know if you can use `memcpy` to change the polymorphic type of one object to another.

Out of my head; not tested:

```cpp
class Animal {
  virtual ~Animal() {}
};

struct Cat : public Animal {
  int lives;
};

struct Dog : public Animal {
  size_t bark_count;
};

Dog* dog = malloc(std::max(sizeof(Dog), sizeof(Cat)));
new (dog) Dog(0);

Cat* cat = malloc(std::max(sizeof(Dog), sizeof(Cat)));
new (cat) Cat(9);

// Make cat a dog. Is this possible?
memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char*>(cat), reinterpret_cast<char*>(dog), sizeof(Dog));
```

I'm assuming that due to the question [When is a type in c++11 allowed to be memcpyed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27009178/1173521), this is invalid behavior. However, I'm not 100% sure, either.

**Context:** I'm writing a type checker and need to 'rewrite' types as more information comes available. I thought about refactoring the `Type` class to a union type but it will require a considerable amount of work. Other approaches are very much welcome.

Comment: Only objects with implicit lifetimes can be created this way see [Object creation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object#Object_creation) and [ImplicitLifetimeType](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ImplicitLifetimeType)

Comment: When it is [triviably copyable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivially_copyable). For me this is not even a language laywer question because this is actually very well defined (no gray areas, no known compiler bugs)

Comment: ... otherwise, it has UB

Comment: Most times when developers ask this is because they are investigating binary serialization (loading/saving from memory to disk/network whatever). It is not a trivial thing to do right. So tell us if this is what you are exploring.

Comment: @PepijnKramer See the last paragraph. I'm writing a type checker that needs to rewrite types in memory.

Comment: Then I will refer you to : [std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast). But still when reinterpreting a piece of memory as another type be careful. Make sure constructors are called and/or lifetime of objects are started.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Ooh that's actually very interesting, thanks!

Comment: Note bit_cast will NOT end the life time of the previous object... so it might not what you are looking for. But it will give you some insights.

Comment: Looks like you will have to make explicit conversion functions (or constructors). Which is in the end not a bad thing.

Comment: @PepijnKramer yeah I was afraid of that ... Ah well I guess I know what to do this Saturday ☺️

Comment: *Would overwriting a polymorphic object byte-by-byte in memory ever be valid in C++?*  **No**.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the `asm` keyword?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm assuming that due to the question When is a type in c++11 allowed to be memcpyed?, this is invalid behavior. However, I'm not 100% sure, either.

Exactly.

Your class is not trivially-copyable due to having a non-trivial destructor because it is `virtual`.

Therefore, copying the object representation with `memcpy` isn't possible at all. Even worse, the types are also not implicit-lifetime and therefore `memcpy` won't create any `Dog` object in the `cat` storage at all. The behavior will be undefined, at a minimum if you actually use the destination buffer as if it contained the `Dog` object. The `memcpy` itself may be ok with some nuances to how exactly you have written the example.

Writing object representation byte-by-byte through character-like pointers isn't covered by the standard currently either way. `memcpy` is just specified as a "magical" function that somehow copies underlying bytes of an object in such a way that if all underlying bytes of a trivially-copyable object were copied into an object of the same type (which may be implicitly-created by `memcpy`), that then the destination object will hold the same value as the source object.

---

`reinterpret_cast<char*>` is pointless btw. `memcpy` wants a `void*` and the conversion to it is implicit.

Comment: Right, that settles it for me. I'll mark this as accepted when the timer allows me.